# How can I create connection to DB2 in RESTXpress?

Tags: web-services, rest, db2

I'm using the RESTXpress engine to create REST services. It works fine with Oracle, but I have an issue with db2 database because db2, besides `db2jcc.jar` driver, requires license jar file `db2jcc_license_c.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

You can repack all classes in one jar file.